# Redshift slow select query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

All,
I have a fact table in redshift with around 90 million rows, max columns are integers and have AUTO sort key and EVEN dist key. 2 nodes cluster. Running a simple select statement taking forever and aborting. Any help.

```
select * from facts_invoice
```

Basically trying to feed this data to Powerbi and seems like the slowness coming from Redshift itself. In Snowflake, I used 200 Billions select * before and never took more than 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Why are you trying to select 90m rows?

Comment: So, I am pulling this to PowerBI and first 15 minutes it keep says waiting...

Comment: Why are you pulling all the data into PowerBI? Are you using Import rather than DirectQuery? If you are then the solution is to use DirectQuery

Comment: You are right. Direct query not going to work as dashboard is initially built on complex calculations which are not supported by direct query. Interesting part is, Microosft recommending import. :)

Comment: Ok - but pulling 90 million rows into PowerBI whenever you want to run a query is also never going to work. You either need to have some significant filtering built into your queries or design a proper set of facts and dimensions in your data warehouse